# SCA Tools - Hierarchical Composition

Tags: eclipse, components, soa, composite, sca

I am using Service Component Architecture (SCA) Tools in eclipse, in order to design and edit XML based SCA diagrams. So far I was able to create a composite within few components.

I am now trying to create a hierarchy of composites where a composite is a component that exists in another composite...and so on. However, I did not know how to achieve this hierarchy in the sca tool of eclipse. Below is my diagram. Any help? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After further reading, I understood that SCA achieves the composite hierarchy by allowing a composite to be the implementation of a component. Something like this:

```
  <sca:component name="Multiplier">
    <sca:implementation.composite name="multiplier_composite:Multiplier"/>
    <sca:service name="multiplier_service">
      <sca:interface.java interface="com.example.multiplierService"/>
    </sca:service>
  </sca:component>
```

The "multiplier_composite" above is a name of a composite defined in a separate file. Thus, the "Multiplier" component above is nothing but a composite. Beautiful.